# Is there a way to get messages from a button inside a groupbox?

Tags: c, winapi, button, groupbox

So I have a groupbox-style button.  I can put a button inside it by creating a button with the groupbox as the parent.  However, if I do that, the groupbox gets the button-click message instead of the window.  Is there any way I can intercept these messages or have them forwarded on?

There *is* an example on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/y6Eaza7A), where instead of putting the button in the groupbox they hover it over the top, however this means that I can't simply make the groupbox and its contents invisible in one command (and it's cheating, so is likely to go wrong at some point).  So, is there a way to do it where the button is actually in the groupbox?

### Example code to create the controls:

```
HWND hSoFGrp = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT, "BUTTON", _T("Group Text"), WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
                                 BS_GROUPBOX | BS_TEXT | BS_LEFT | BS_TOP,
                                 0, 250, 150, 100, hwnd, (HMENU) 40,
                                 GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        
HWND hSoFBtn = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "BUTTON", _T("Button"), WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
                                 BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_CENTER | BS_TEXT | BS_VCENTER | BS_MULTILINE,
                                 100, 15, 48, 30, hSoFGrp, (HMENU) 41,
                                 GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

### Example code to handle the messages:

```
switch (msg)
{
  case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 40)
    {
       //This would be messages from the groupbox
    }
    else if (LOWORD(wParam) == 41)
    {
       //This would be messages from the button if the groupbox wasn't intercepting them!
    }
  break;
}
```

So, is it possible?

Comment: Make your button a sibling of the group box, not a child. You can still position the button inside the group box. It's not cheating, this is how they're designed to work.

Comment: If you do put the button inside the groupbox as a child, you can subclass the groupbox with `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubclass()` to access messages sent to it.

Comment: Note that another side effect of making the buttons children of the groupbox is that normal dialog keyboard handling will break.

Answer (score 1):

Group boxes are typically not used as parent windows to the controls visibly contained within them.  The hierarchical structure of `HWND`s does not necessarily match the visible organization of controls.  Instead you should make the group box a sibling of its grouped controls.

Note that the group box should be positioned immediately before (above) its grouped controls in z-order; that way activating the mnemonic from the group box label will move focus to the first control in the group.  Even though the group box control will be above its grouped controls, [a group box explicitly allows other controls to draw themselves over it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100712-00/?p=13453).